# How to set email body text color with GmailApp

Tags: html, google-apps-script, gmail

How do I make the email's body text pink?

```
function myFunction() {
   GmailApp.createDraft("user@gmail.com" ,"Subject", "Hi! This text should be pink.");
}
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#createDraft(String,String,String,Object) use the htmlBody option.

Comment: Also, please read 'How to ask'. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @c0de I have come a long time and have not found it. (developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {

var body = '<font color="pink">Hi! This text should be pink.</font>';

GmailApp.createDraft("user@gmail.com" , "Subject", "", {htmlBody: body});
}
```